# Remix OS Android Kernel Upgrade

Tags: kernel, android-versions, android-x86, android-pc, remix-os

I have recently Installed Remix OS on my pc. I found out that the linux kernel version on this version of Remix OS is 4.4.3 which doesnot support dual band wifi. How can I upgrade the linux kernel ?

Comment: Are you sure it's related? My Ubuntu machine runs 4.4.x kernel and detects AC WiFi just fine.

Comment: Upgrading kernel (major version) in Android is far not as easy as on proper Linux distros, usually only comes with an upgrade in the OS itself. Additionally, from what I've seen in the Android-x86 Google Groups discussion, 4.4 is by far the latest "stable" version for Ax86, while newer ones like 4.8 and 4.10 are still experimental.

Comment: I have Intel 3168. Which is not recognized....